# Let $T:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n $ be Symmetric, $tr({T^2})=0$. Show that $T=0$.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $T:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n $ be Symmetric Linear Transformation such that $tr({T^2})=0$. Show that $T=0$.

Comment: Did you try anything on this problem?  Do you have any thoughts or attempts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will use spectral theorem to proove it
[image]

So $\lambda_i=o~\forall ~i$ So $D=0$ and therefore $T=0$.

Answer (score 3):

If $\{ e_j \}_{j=1}^{n}$ is the standard basis for $\mathbb{R}^{n}$, then
$$
       \mbox{tr}(T^{2}) = \sum_{j=1}^{n}\langle T^{2}e_j,e_j\rangle,
$$
where $\langle x, y\rangle = y^{T}x$ is the Euclidean inner product.
Because $T$ is symmetric,
$$
       \mbox{tr}(T^{2})=\sum_{j=1}^{n}\langle Te_j,Te_j\rangle=\sum_{j=1}^{n}\|Te_j\|^{2}
$$
Therefore, if $\mbox{tr}(T^{2})=0$, then $Te_j=0$ for all $j$, which makes $T=0$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: The operator $T$ is orthogonally diagonalizable, so there exists an orthogonal basis $\mathcal{B}$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$ such that

$$ [T]^{\mathcal{B}}_{\mathcal{B}} = A = \mathrm{diag}(\lambda_1, \ldots, \lambda_n) $$

where $\lambda_i \in \mathbb{R}$. Translate the information on $T$ to information regarding $A$.

Answer (score 1):

- $T^t=T$
- $tr(T T^t)=\|T\|^2=0\Leftrightarrow T=0.$